# google maps api shoutcast live listeners

Tags: google-maps, shoutcast

Looking to add a simple globe world map with red dots for live shoutcast listeners, could someone help with this as i have no idea on where to start apart from i have my api key.

I also have my own VPS server but not sure this matters as i run my shoutcast on there and have been reading https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key but cant get it to work?

I get this error message:

> The Google Maps APS server rejected your request, The "sensor£ parameter specified in the request must be set to true or false

The Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>  <head>    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />    <style type="text/css">      html { height: 100% }      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }      #map_canvas { height: 100% }    </style>    <script type="text/javascript"      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcdTcPLIl1aQEO4SO0RQkJE-X-UacZkXY&sensor=TRUE">    </script>    <script type="text/javascript">      function initialize() {        var myOptions = {          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),          zoom: 8,          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP        };        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),            myOptions);      }    </script>  
<title>Test Google Maps</title>
</head>  
<body onload="initialize()">    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>  
</body></html>
```

Comment: All I can say is you seem to be a little over your head, if all you know is that code. While we are here to help, we are not here to code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change TRUE to true and it works